# Is there a way to get the retry number in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use retry logic in jenkins declarative pipeline, when the retry is happening i need to add additional logic. For that I need retry number so that I can use variable to add additional logic. As a temporary solution i am trying to code as below for which counter variable is not getting incremented. Please help.

```
steps{
    script{
        def counter=0
        retry(3){
            //my original logic
            if (counter.toInteger()>0){
                //my additional logic
            }
            counter = counter + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there's an open issue in jenkins for this here: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-49341

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution.. Hope it helps someone.

```
count= (binding.hasVariable('count)) ? count + 1 : 1
```